# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setToken is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, token

I am having trouble with React while trying to set a token for user to log into the application. I followed the steps here to create a login process but it gives out the Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setToken is not a function error and I am not able to correct it.

Here are the associated codes starting with from app.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Login from './Pages/Login.js';
import Signup from './Pages/Signup';
import Dashboard from './Pages/Dashboard.js';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import useToken from './Pages/useToken'

function App() {

  const { token, setToken } = useToken();

  if (!token) {
    return <Login setToken={setToken} />
  };

  return (
    <div className="">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
                <Login />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/dashboard">
                <Dashboard />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/signup">
                <Signup />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Login.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

async function loginUser(credentials) {
 return fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
 })
   .then(data => data.json())
}


const Login = ({setToken}) => {
    // username is email address
    const [username, setUsername] = useState();
    const [password, setPassword] = useState();

    const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const token = await loginUser({
            username,
            password
        });

        setToken(token);

    };

    return (<>
            <section>
                <div className="flex items-center justify-center flex-col">
                    <div className="w-11/15 mt-24 rounded-lg flex flex-col items-center justify-center relative">
                        <span className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row">
                            <header className="text-5xl pr-4">Welcome to </header>
                            <header className="font-LoveloLine text-6xl font-bold text-center"> Mused</header>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <div className="flex items-center justify-center flex-col">
                    <div className=" lg:w-2/4 px-4 rounded-lg flex flex-col items-center justify-center relative" >
                        <div className="py-12">
                            <form action="" className="flex flex-col gap-2" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                {/* Email address */}
                                <label htmlFor=""></label>
                                <input className="w-96 text-brand-Black bg-white border-brand-Blue rounded-lg py-3 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-brand-Red focus:border-transparent" type="email" name="" placeholder="Email address" id="" onChange={(e) => { setUsername(e.target.value)}} />
                                <label htmlFor=""></label>
                                {/* Password */}
                                <input className="w-96 bg-white text-brand-Black border-brand-Blue rounded-lg py-3 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-brand-Red focus:border-transparent" type="password" name="" placeholder="Password" id="" onChange={(e) => { setPassword(e.target.value)}} />
                                <div class="max-w-sm mx-auto py-4">
                                    <label class="inline-flex items-center">
                                    <input class="text-brand-Blue w-6 h-6 mr-2 focus:ring-indigo-400 focus:ring-opacity-25 border border-gray-300 rounded" type="checkbox" />
                                    Remember me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                {/* Login button */}
                                <div>
                                    <button type="submit" className="bg-brand-Blue rounded-full w-full py-2 active:bg-brand-Blue-dark hover:bg-brand-Blue-dark">Login</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            {/* Checkbox */}
                                {/* Signup button */}
                            <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center ">
                                <p className="py-6">or</p>
                                <button type="submit" className="bg-brand-Red rounded-full w-full py-2 active:bg-brand-Red-dark hover:bg-brand-Red-dark">Signup
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </>


    )
};

Login.propTypes = {
    setToken: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default Login
```

Error is thrown for Login.js file "setToken(token)" function. It is not supposed to be a function

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

const useToken = () => {
    const getToken = () => {
        const tokenString = localStorage.getItem("token");
        const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
        return userToken?.token
    };

    const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());
    
    const saveToken = (userToken) => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(userToken));
        setToken(userToken.token);
        
    }
    return {
        setToken: saveToken,
        token
    }

}

export default useToken
```

Comment: You didn't pass the `setToken` function to `<Login />` inside `Route` component.

Comment: Please I have the same issue, i have passed it inside my login route still is not working, you has gotten the solution

Answer (score 0):

In my own case i discovered that I was passing the setToken function inside login route like this:

`<Route path='/login setToken={setToken} />`
instead of

```
 <Route path='/login' exact element={<Login 
                    setToken={setToken}
                    />}
                    />
```

You have to pass it to the component itself, not the route!

Answer (score 0):

Your posting this as within only the component, as soon as you go to the route it disregards it. So from `localhost:3000` it'll work fine, but because you've not passed it through the route `setToken={token}` it'll disregard it. Scratched my head at this for hours.